# Do US citizens need any visas while on a cruise in the Mediterranean?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens

We're taking a cruise on the Norwegian Epic in late September 2017, departing Barcelona with stops in Italy, France, and returning to Spain. Besides my US passport, do I need any sort of a visa for this trip?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you haven't previously stayed in the Schengen area for [90 days out of the past 180](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work), a US passport should be sufficient to make this trip.